# Issue While Deleting the object in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

When Cell reaches the 4th indexpath I want to delete  first two object in the array .Here's the code

```
if(indexPath.row == 4)
{

     NSLog(@"count1 : %@",sharedClass.potentialmatchesArray);
    [sharedClass.potentialmatchesArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [sharedClass.potentialmatchesArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
     NSLog(@"count2 : %@",sharedClass.potentialmatchesArray);


}
```

how to reload the tableview in cellforrow?Pls Help me..

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You may be thinking about your problem in a wrong way.

Comment: When the table is asking you for cells is the **wrong** time to be adjusting the backing array.  Decide how many rows you want to show first, then reload the data.

Comment: tats my task..after 4th index path..if i scroll up i don't want to see the first index path.

Comment: What if the user scrolls the other way, should they reappear?

Comment: no it should permanently delete the object - #Koen